# why can't I type enter instead of heving a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input textbox in HTML, and I would like that when I press ENTER on the specific input, it performs a function:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="English" id="englinput" onkeypress="enterEvent()">
```

How should my javascript code look to perform something like this:

```
function enterEvent() {   
   document.getElementById('btnport').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
   document.getElementById('btnstart').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Answer (score 2):

`onkeypress` is passing an event object, you probably have to mute default submitting of the form with `event.preventDefault()`.

```
function enterEvent(event) {
   event.preventDefault()  
   document.getElementById('btnport').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
   document.getElementById('btnstart').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

You can use `if (event.which === 13 || event.keyCode === 13)` inside to add a custom action for ENTER key.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to detect the Enter key, you need to capture the event, so the attribute `onkeypress` should be: `onkeypress="enterEvent(event)"`

Then, in your javascript code you need to validate that key event:

```js
function enterEvent(event){
    if(event.keyCode === 13){
        event.preventDefault();

        document.getElementById('btnport').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('btnstart').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

```css
#btnport { visibility: hidden }
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="English" id="englinput" onkeypress="enterEvent(event)">

<button id="btnport">Port</button>
<button id="btnstart">Start</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. but I wnat now the function to call anther function, but it doesn't work. I did it like that:  ```` function enterEvent(event){
    if(event.keyCode === 13){
        event.preventDefault();
        
        return function (test())
       
    }
} ```` but it gives an error

Comment: you have a bad return.. so, instead of `return function (test()) ` just call the function  or return it directly: `return test()`